# Content hub site policy not deleting or making sites read only

Tags: 2013, content, content-type-hub, group-policy

In our Sharepoint 2013 POC environment I have created a content hub site and setup a site policy to test deletions of sites.
The policy has definetly been subscribed by the test site and it shows “this site will be deleted" ......(2 days ago) The problem is the site is not ready only as I have been able to upload & edit new files and the site is still available despite passing the deletion period. Anyone able to shed light on this issue would be really appreciated 
Note: I have checked Content Hub & Content Hub subscriber timer jobs are running

Comment: I am researching this as well. Still looking for a concrete answer, but it seems another setting must be configured to send confirmation e-mails to the site collection admin. See these articles: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262420.aspx http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262509.aspx